# Native code plugin for the most popular browsers

Tags: c++, browser, native-code

I need to write plugins for the most popular browsers such as:

- Google Chrome
- Opera
- Mozilla Firefox
- Safari
- Edge
- Yandex Browser

The problem is:
I have to use C++, cause I'm not enough skilled in web languages. Also I'm using extra lib for C++: OpenCV. Is there any ways of creating multiplatform cross-browser plugin? I have to add, that this plugin is only for PC version of browser.
If there is no such way, please tell me, how to make plugin for each browser using C++.

Comment: The question, as it stands, is too broad. SO is not a tutorial provider.

Comment: The only way i know how to handle this in C++ is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Creating_Custom_Firefox_Extensions_with_the_Mozilla_Build_System but this is deprecated so you shouldnt use it anymore!!!

Try to learn JavaScript, TypeScript or so... If you´re working in the web use the technology of the web!
Try to setup an http Server which handles the tasks u use OpenCV for and make the calls to this Server from the Browser Plugin written in JS/TS

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can have a look at [emscripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/), it translates c++ code to javascript using llvm.

Comment: Doesnt Work, since he uses OpenCV